# Tensorflow: What parameters of the model/decoder of the audio recognition network need to be changed to speed up the performance?

Tags: tensorflow, speech-recognition

I ran the [Tensorflow audio recognition tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/tutorials/audio_recognition) for wake word detection. For a given input wavefile, the model returns the result in approximately 5 seconds.

Is there a way to reduce this time to 100s of milliseconds by changing the model parameters during training? I came across [this link that relates to optimizing the graph obtained](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/11618), but I want to know what are the training parameters itself that I can risk manipulating so that the response time is reduced further without affecting the quality of the model.

The training parameters are:

```py
parser.add_argument(
  '--background_volume',
  type=float,
  default=0.1,
  help="""\
  How loud the background noise should be, between 0 and 1.
  """)
parser.add_argument(
  '--background_frequency',
  type=float,
  default=0.8,
  help="""\
  How many of the training samples have background noise mixed in.
  """)
parser.add_argument(
  '--silence_percentage',
  type=float,
  default=10.0,
  help="""\
  How much of the training data should be silence.
  """)
parser.add_argument(
  '--unknown_percentage',
  type=float,
  default=10.0,
  help="""\
  How much of the training data should be unknown words.
  """)
parser.add_argument(
  '--time_shift_ms',
  type=float,
  default=100.0,
  help="""\
  Range to randomly shift the training audio by in time.
  """)
parser.add_argument(
  '--testing_percentage',
  type=int,
  default=10,
  help='What percentage of wavs to use as a test set.')
parser.add_argument(
  '--validation_percentage',
  type=int,
  default=10,
  help='What percentage of wavs to use as a validation set.')
parser.add_argument(
  '--sample_rate',
  type=int,
  default=16000,
  help='Expected sample rate of the wavs',)
parser.add_argument(
  '--clip_duration_ms',
  type=int,
  default=1000,
  help='Expected duration in milliseconds of the wavs',)
parser.add_argument(
  '--window_size_ms',
  type=float,
  default=30.0,
  help='How long each spectrogram timeslice is',)
parser.add_argument(
  '--window_stride_ms',
  type=float,
  default=10.0,
  help='How long each spectrogram timeslice is',)
parser.add_argument(
  '--dct_coefficient_count',
  type=int,
  default=40,
  help='How many bins to use for the MFCC fingerprint',)
parser.add_argument(
  '--how_many_training_steps',
  type=str,
  default='15000,3000',
  help='How many training loops to run',)
parser.add_argument(
  '--eval_step_interval',
  type=int,
  default=400,
  help='How often to evaluate the training results.')
parser.add_argument(
  '--learning_rate',
  type=str,
  default='0.001,0.0001',
  help='How large a learning rate to use when training.')
parser.add_argument(
  '--batch_size',
  type=int,
  default=100,
  help='How many items to train with at once',)
parser.add_argument(
  '--summaries_dir',
  type=str,
  default='/tmp/retrain_logs',
  help='Where to save summary logs for TensorBoard.')
parser.add_argument(
  '--wanted_words',
  type=str,
  default='yes,no,up,down,left,right,on,off,stop,go',
  help='Words to use (others will be added to an unknown label)',)
parser.add_argument(
  '--train_dir',
  type=str,
  default='/tmp/speech_commands_train',
  help='Directory to write event logs and checkpoint.')
parser.add_argument(
  '--save_step_interval',
  type=int,
  default=100,
  help='Save model checkpoint every save_steps.')
parser.add_argument(
  '--start_checkpoint',
  type=str,
  default='',
  help='If specified, restore this pretrained model before any training.')
parser.add_argument(
  '--model_architecture',
  type=str,
  default='conv',
  help='What model architecture to use')
parser.add_argument(
  '--check_nans',
  type=bool,
  default=False,
  help='Whether to check for invalid numbers during processing')
```

Comment: Please add 4 more spaces before your code block for better readability.

Comment: Is the 5 seconds just time spent inside the `session.run` call, or does it include time to restore the graph/checkpoint and start a session? May make sense to benchmark these separately; both parts can be optimized, but it's important to pick the right one.

Comment: @Allen Lavoie, I am sorry I am unable to answer your questions as of now as I am a tensorflow novice. In lay terms, once I have obtained the model, for a given input wave file it takes 5 seconds to give me the output score.

Comment: Also,for the following code                                                                   
    `bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/transform_graph --in_graph=/home/cogknit/tensorflow/my_frozen_graph.pb  --out_graph=optimized_frozen_graph.pb --inputs='Mul' --outputs='softmax' --transforms='                               
  strip_unused_nodes(type=float, shape="[]")
  remove_nodes(op=Identity, op=CheckNumerics)
  fold_constants(ignore_errors=true)
  fold_batch_norms
  fold_old_batch_norms' ` I get the following error: Input node softmax not found in graph.

Comment: I overcame the above error by using the summarize_graph tool to get the --inputs= and --outputs= (which here was  'wav_data' and 'labels_softmax' respectively if I am not wrong) and obtained the optimized graph but there doesn't seem to be a significant reduction in the response time. Can you suggest the other ways this time can be reduced?